# Turning a String Decimal To String Int by Using Regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have below string;

```
line='P1: 6.0, P2: 5.0, P3: 10.3, P4: 7.0, P5: 10.0, P6: 6.0, P7: 4.0, P8: 5.8, P9: 5.0, P10: 5.0'
```

I only want to delete .0's and keep the values like 4.5 or 10.3. So what I want is like,

```
line='P1: 6, P2: 5, P3: 10.3, P4: 7, P5: 10, P6: 6, P7: 4., P8: 5.8, P9: 5, P10: 5'
```

I tried to do this,

```py
import re
re.sub(r'.0(?=,)','',line)
```

It didn't work. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please be more descriptive that "didn't work" - what happened? Error? Unexpected results?

Comment: Actually it works but not for the last element of the string. Output is ''P1: 6, P2: 5, P3: 10.3, P4: 7, P5: 10, P6: 6, P7: 4, P8: 5.8, P9: 5, P10: 5.0''

Comment: You could also use `re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\.0(?![^,])','',line)` to make sure you only remove `.0` after a digit and before a comma/end of string.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Wow! that looks complex, thanks a lot for clarification and the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can just do a simple replace, for example:

```py
line = "P1: 6.0, P2: 5.0, P3: 10.3, P4: 7.0, P5: 10.0, P6: 6.0, P7: 4.0, P8: 5.8, P9: 5.0, P10: 5.0"


print(line.replace('.0', ''))
>>> P1: 6, P2: 5, P3: 10.3, P4: 7, P5: 10, P6: 6, P7: 4, P8: 5.8, P9: 5, P10: 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is much more easy :)

Comment: @svn_21 Try `'5.05'.replace('.0', '')`, do you expect this?

Comment: u can only use this like @WiktorStribiżew mentioned if they have only one decimal digit.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew The data has only one decimal numbers, so above code worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
re.sub(r'\b\.0\b', '', line)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/oiKX5s/1).

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `\.` | '.' |
| `0` | '0' |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##Nc5NCsMgEAXgvacYXCUgojV/FXqHHEAoCNJm0UTGCbSnt0Zw9/GYN7z4o/exm5y3TzyQAAPD8ApfeABy551UznNGIdEzEZaUr9rCJJWA9WZhrDAWtJKmaLAw12is0aWpnc8Whorl6i0F9/ZAqyrOIm47dRhkOn1XhwjgXEAb0Pcs5z8)**:

```py
import re
regex = r"\b\.0\b"
test_str = "P1: 6.0, P2: 5.0, P3: 10.3, P4: 7.0, P5: 10.0, P6: 6.0, P7: 4.0, P8: 5.8, P9: 5.0, P10: 5.0"
print(re.sub(regex, "", test_str))
```

**Results**: `P1: 6, P2: 5, P3: 10.3, P4: 7, P5: 10, P6: 6, P7: 4, P8: 5.8, P9: 5, P10: 5`